# My web page is displaying differently on my new laptop screen

Tags: html, css

I used div tags to create the layout of my web page after which I added a backgroud image and positioned the div tag using external css. Here is what is looks like.

```
<div id="headerTag">
```

My external css looks like this:

```
#headerTag{
background:url(../a/b/c.png);
background-size:150px;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
position:relative;
top:100px;
Left:20px;
Width:150px;
Height:50px;
}
```

Everything worked fine and well as I desired but the problem is:  I had issues with the laptop I used to create the app and the laptop was acer travellmate. So I got another laptop which was compaq presario A900 and transferred the app from my old laptop to my new laptop. When I tried to run the app from my new laptop, the jsf page had a different look from how it was on my old laptop. I mean all my div tags were scattered, the background images in them were soo big that only half of it showed in the div tags but the function/ methods of my business logic are working properly. 
Please I need help on how to send everything back to normal. I changed my screen resolution but it had no effect. Am suspecting the difference of screen size to be the problem because the screen of my new laptop is a lot bigger than that of my old laptop.

Am also suspecting the graphics card driver of my new laptop cause I formatted it with windows 7.

Am just confused can someone please help me.

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of HTML and CSS. Were you not also using a different browser version by any chance? Say, on your old laptop you were using IE8 and on your new one you're using IE11? Also note that it might not have anything to do with that tiny snippet, more likely it is the styling of the container element that has cross-browser problems. Finally: why the java tag? This has nothing to do with java at all.

Comment: Different resolution? Assuming your HTML isn't different between the old and new laptops, why would your jsf and xhtml and css matter?

Comment: This is not a cross-browser problem, but (to be frank) cluelessness. You obviously don't know what `position: relative` does, otherwise you wouldn't be using it. You could probably post your complete code here, but that won't help. You'll need to rewrite your code from the ground up (and stay away from `position`- you don't need it).